# Как писать media запросы в sass?

Tags: sass

Адаптирую вёрстку, нужно написать следующий код в  синтаксисе sass, то есть без скобок и точек с запятой

```
@media(max-width:1400px){
        .container{
            max-width: none
        }
   }
```

Comment: Так уберите фигурные скобки и приведите в порядок табуляцию (https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/css/). Будет то, что Вы хотите. Ну или не используйте Sass в чистом виде (это издевательство), используйте диалект SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 1400px)
  .container
    max-width: none
```